# How to fulfill blank fields in Open Refine?

Tags: data-cleaning, openrefine

I found the blank rows, that is already great. Now I want to type "Not informed Value" to all blank values, but I don´t know how, Any hints.

Thanks in advance! I am having a great fun working with this distributed community! 
Joni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "facet by blank-> true"  to isolate the blank cells, then  click "transform" on the same column and type the text you want  between quotes.

It's also possible to perform the operation with a GREL formula (using "transform"):

```
if(isBlank(value.trim()), "Not informed Value", value)
```

Finally, since Open Refine 2.7, you can apply this kind of formula to each columns at once. Just click on "All -> Transform" and use the formula above.

[image]

Comment: That worked nicely, actually it was a vary trick movement man! Congrats and thanks for the support!

Comment: Do you know if there is a command to spot all missing values of the dataset at once?

Comment: Absolutely great! Thanks!